# Java enum function return value

Tags: java, enums, return

I'm trying to make a simple script that will return the velue of an enum, let's just give an example:
//EG.class (should return the Animal ID.

```
import Object.Animal;

public class EG {
    public void main() {
        Animal AnimalID = Object.Animal.CAT;

        System.out.print(AnimalID);
        //Should return value of CAT: 2000 (long)
        //But I can't figure out what's wrong.
    }
}
```

//Object.class

```
public class Object {
    public enum Animal {
        CAT(2000L), DOG(2001L), MONKEY(2002L), TIGER(2003L);

        private long animal;

        private Animal(long a) {
          animal = a;
        }

        public long getAnimal() {
          return animal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void main()` should be  `public static void main(String args[])`

Comment: See some sample code at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call `System.out.print(AnimalID.getAnimal());`

Answer (score 6):

Why not just create a `toString()` method on the `Animal` enum?

```
public enum Animal {
    CAT(2000L), DOG(2001L), MONKEY(2002L), TIGER(2003L);

    private long animal;

    private Animal(long a) {
      animal = a;
    }

    public long getAnimal() {
      return animal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
       return this.name() + ": " +animal;
    }
}
```